# Can I use $_SESSION as memcache?

Tags: php, session

Every time a page is loaded I connect to the database to fetch the `settings` table where the basic application settings are stored. It looks uneficcient. I have an idea to temporary store the `$settings` array in $_SESSION variable. So every time the script is started it checks if $_SESSION['settings'] is empty and loads the data from DB only if it is.

My questions are:

1)Is this normal practice or there are serious pitfalls?

2)Will this speed up my application?

Comment: Without testing guesses are guesses :) memcached, a database, and "session data" serve a different purpose. For instance, neither memcached nor a DB have an implicit association with a *session* while `$_SESSION` is inherently *tied to sessions* (e.g. per client).

Comment: sessions are stored in files by default, not memory btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess performance benefits of this would be negligible at best, and potentially harmful at worst.

Either way $_SESSION isn't really intended to be used this way, it's for data relating to a specific user, and as a general rule I try to keep it as concise as possible.

A better solution you might consider is caching the settings locally as a PHP file, it's not too hard to script something up to generate a file that creates a simple key => value array from the database that you can include. e.g.

```
<?php
// myconfig.php

return array(
    'mysetting' => 'value',
);
```

Then you can just include this file to get your config values:

```
<?php
// app.php

$config = include('myconfig.php');

echo $config['mysetting']; // 'value'
```

Answer (score 5):

> It looks unefficient.

it *looks* or it IS inefficient?

> I have an idea to temporary store the $settings array in $_SESSION variable.

That's wrong idea. Sessions are for personal data, not site-wide settings. If you want to read your settings from a file - include it!

> Will this speed up my application?

Is anything wrong with your application speed at the moment?

Comment: Good approach, Col. Shrapnel: _If something is not broken, do not fix it!_ Premature optimization can easily spoil the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using PHP's `$_SESSION` as a local cache. For each visitor that comes to your site, you'll need to populate that `$_SESSION` variable. This is inefficient, since each visitor will get a session when they don't need. It's also difficult to manage, since changes to your `settings` data won't immediately be populated into the `$_SESSION` variable. I'd recommend something like [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or even [apc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) local object cache for this.